# Django authenticating android app user

Tags: android, python, django, django-authentication

What I am planning to do:

- Authenticate user using FB/Google on the client side(on the phone)
- Pass the authentication confirmation to the server
- Create another token to use for future communication with app

So I would write a "login" app that will create this token and that's it.

My problem:

Since all the data is mapped to UserID, how do I map the token to the user ID?

- Do I write a Django middleware that does this conversion?
- Do I store current_token in the User object
- Do I store a map of token -> userId and use this when generating data that templates will use?

**or**

Do I store the user_id locally and pass it along with the token?

Answer (score 0):

> What I am planning to do:
>
> - Authenticate user using FB/Google on the client side(on the phone)
> - Pass the authentication confirmation to the server
> - Create another token to use for future communication with app

You never, **ever**, do user validation on the client side.

Social validation also happens through the server-side using the API of the openID provider (in this case, Google/Facebook).

What you are going to do is to use one of these 4 found here:

https://hackerluddite.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/review-of-4-django-social-auth-apps/

Test each of them out, see which 1 fits your needs.

What you aren't going to do is to build out your own social registration tool.

The biggest reason being that is has already been built and tested for you, so you don't need to reinvent the wheel, unless you are doing so for the sake of learning.

Security is also important, and you can consider your own solution to be less secure than a tested version.

Comment: So I'd pass the Username & Password to the server?

Comment: In the case of social login, you will not be passing anything. The social login should redirect the user to a facebook/google login, where user-auth is handled by their services. Letting third-party sites handle usernames/passwords is a security risk. If you are trying to store user-info, you will need to consult their respective APIs to understand how to do it (although I hope that 1 of the auth tools allows you to grab user data and put it into your own DB).

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I do entirely understand how this would work on an app. As in, what does "re-direction" mean in an app? Do I open a web view? 

Even when logging in on the app side, I will be using the tools FB & google provide and not re-write anything.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. Could you re-explain please?